# What is the best approach for Digital Signing a CSV file?

Tags: .net, vb.net, csv, security, signedxml

I am a newbie to Digital Signing and would like some advice on the best approach for this.  I have an application in VB.net that does data logging to a CSV file.  I need to provide a digital signature to the CSV file and from my research, it looks like converting the CSV file to an XML document would allow me to use the SignedXML class and its properties.  The other option would be to sign the CSV document, but I am not sure what .Net tools are available for this.  If I sign the CSV file, would it make sense to give it a new extension like .sif instead of .csv?  Any advice would be appreciated!

Comment: Signing is of course only half the job - there's no point signing if nothing's verifying - so who/what will be doing verification and do they impose any constraints on what you can do?

Comment: I need to basically take the data in a datatable and save it in a CSV file.  I know how to do that.  I have figured out how to convert the CSV file into an XML file and then use SignXML to sign the file.  The problem with that method is that the stored XML file is very large compared to the original CSV file.  I am wondering if a good approach would then be to zip or compress the signed xml file and store it as a compressed file or convert the csv file to a binary file, then sign the binary file. I am not sure how to do that.